# What is the name of this character |

Tags: special-characters

I am writing a documentation on a PHP framework. I make a lot use of this | character. It is some kind of separator, but does anyone know the exact name of it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site to ask questions specific to programming, not character identification.

Comment: Wow guys don't you see the date on this question, it was from 2010! I am pretty sure StackOverflow was the only site back then. I got 6 -1's on this question today :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Vertical bar or Pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar):

> The **vertical bar ( | )** is a computer character and [glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) with various uses in mathematics, computing, and typography. It has many names, often related to particular meanings: [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke) (in [logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic)), **verti-bar**, **vbar**, **stick**, **vertical line**, **vertical slash**, **bar, **obelisk**, or **pipe**...

Answer (score 12):

"Vertical Bar" or "pipe" [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar)

Answer (score 10):

http://catb.org/jargon/html/A/ASCII.html

> Common: bar; or; or-bar; v-bar; pipe;
>   vertical bar. Rare: ;
>   gozinta; thru; pipesinta (last three
>   from UNIX); [spike].

Comment: +1 for "gozinta"! I don't know where that comes from but I like it and I think I'm going to start using it exclusively :)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: "gozinta" = "goes into", i.e. is piped into.

Answer (score 2):

I always called it the "pipe character" from UNIX.

Wikipedia thinks it's just a "[vertical bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar)"

Comment: In typesetting it is vertical bar.

Answer (score 2):

I've always called it a pipe... HTML encoding calls it a "Vertical Bar" - HTML CODE: |